# How can I send only RDP traffic over Cisco AnyConnect VPN tunnel?

Tags: vpn, cisco-anyconnect, split-tunnel

My company just switched our VPN to a token based authentication using the Cisco AnyConnect.  However it is routing all traffic across the VPN.  Is there a way I can route only the RDP traffic across the VPN and let everything else use a non-tunneled connection? Maybe with netsh? I am running Vista 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Possible options to use:

- ACL (access lists) on the router
- I suppose you have a firewall behind it, only accept RDP for these incoming connections.

Comment: Let me clarify.  How can I tell the machine I am on to only send the RDP that I initiate on the machine to use the VPN and send all other traffic on the non-tunnel.  The way the VPN software is set up, I cannot reach anything in my LAN with the VPN connected.

Comment: Your current config is a FULL TUNNEL sslvpn setup
you should setup SPLIT TUNNEL sslvpn setup
maybe this could help :http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a0080975e83.shtml